# jQuery selectors issue

Tags: jquery, html

So, I've a  list with many li items, in each one I've 2DIVs with display:none; I want when it's click on a link to appear divs each one of them to open.

The problem is following when it's clicked on link appear every divs..

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="song-info">
    <ul>
        <li class="attr"><a href="#" class="lycris">LYCRIS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="attr"><a href="#" class="credits">CREDITS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="purchase"><a href="#">BuY</a>
        </li>
        <li><span class="playyt"></span> 
        </li>
        <li class="track-duration">(4:18)</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- /.song-info -->
<div class="cf"></div>

<div class="container-lycris"> <a href="http://www.nirvana.com">Nirvana</a> Nevermind</div>

<div class="container-credits"> <a href="http://www.nirvana.com">Nirvana</a> Nevermind</div>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(function(){
       var lycris = $(".lycris");
       var credits = $(".credits");

       $(lycris).click(function(){
          $('.container-lycris').toggleClass("block");
       });  

       $(credits).click(function(){
          $('.container-credits').toggleClass("block");
       });

    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just use jQuery `.toggle()` ? 
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: `$(this).closest('.song-info').find('.container-lycris').toggleClass("block");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the contents of `.container-lycris` and `.container-credits` is actually just you given them different names to identify between the two (your description implies everything is actually named the same), you need to specify the target from another.  Easily doable with the `data` attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        var lycris = $(".lycris");
        $(lycris).click(function() {
            $('*[data-id="' + $(this).data('tar') + '"]').toggleClass("block");
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.container-lycris {
    display: none;
}

.block {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="song-info">
    <ul>
        <li class="attr"><a class="lycris" data-tar="1" href="#">LYCRIS</a></li>
        <li class="attr"><a class="lycris" data-tar="2" href="#">CREDITS</a></li>
        <li class="purchase"><a href="#">BuY</a></li>
        <li><span class="playyt"></span></li>
        <li class="track-duration">(4:18)</li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /.song-info -->

<div class="cf"></div>

<div data-id="1" class="container-lycris">
    <a href="http://www.nirvana.com">Nirvana</a> Nevermind 1
</div>

<div data-id="2" class="container-lycris">
    <a href="http://www.nirvana.com">Nirvana</a> Nevermind 2
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsukasadt/d4bf6fLa/

Since the functionality is identical between the two `click()` functions you had, just use the same classes and assign different `data` IDs.  No reason to make two functions that do the exact same thing.

I hope this helps. ^^

Comment: Thank for you solutions, it works! I've changed a bit to adding toggleClass with animation, 'function in function'. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You're basically building tabs, so you can use the index of the list item to reference the content:

```
$(function () {
    $('.song-info-selector ul li a').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).parent('li').index();
        $('.song-info-content > div').hide().eq(index).show();
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/d4bf6fLa/2/)

Note that I restructured the HTML a bit to group like elements and changed your classes to suit.

Comment: where to put this line ? I put on click action and now, nothing happening

Comment: I understand your question better now. See my updated answer.